# Global variable is not getting updated on Nodejs, on logging the results

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, server

I am using requsts package to call api from another server. But the global variable outside the function is not getting updated and showing undefined.

```
var request = require('request');
var contractAddress;
var abi;

request('http://expressanthem:9000/getcontractAddress',function(error,response,body){
    contractAddress=body;
    console.log(contractAddress+" "+"contract address at first");
});

request('http://expressanthem:9000/getcontractAbi',function(error,response,body1){
    // contract=body1;
    // console.log(typeof contract);
    abi=body1;
    console.log(abi+" "+"This is the abi at first");
}); 
console.log("The contractAddress is"+" "+contractAddress);
console.log("The cotractABI is"+" "+abi);

module.exports={
   contractAddress,
   abi
};
```

The global varibale ABI and contract address is giving values undefined.

Comment: Please read on aync nature of Node.js and callbacks in javascript. You will get your answer.

Comment: request is asynchronous. The problem here is that you try to log your result before the querry is finished. To handle asynchronous operation I recommend to read about promise or async / await